# MediaPlayer obj.addTimedTextSource Runtime exception in Nexus.4.4

Tags: android, media-queries, android-mediaplayer, subtitle

```
mPlayer.addTimedTextSource(mCCPath, MediaPlayer.MEDIA_MIMETYPE_TEXT_SUBRIP);
```

This code is working in many devices,but shows Exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: failure code: -38 error with  java.lang.RuntimeException:   failure code: -38 Asus Nexus 7 (v4.3) and Sony xperia.

Comment: Did you find any solution?